# Darktable 2.4 : how to display hidden presets of base curves?

Tags: darktable

In the base curve module of darktable (2.4), when I push the presets button I can choose among a series of base curves with only two options for Nikon cameras: "Nikon like" and "Nikon Like Alternate".
The "Nikon Like" is the default but the "Nikon like alternate" is better to my taste.

When I go into Preferences/Presets/Base curve there are much more presets available, including for example "Nikon D7000", "Nikon D7200", "Nikon D90".
I would like to have the choice between these different curves from the base curve module in order to use the one that looks best to me (I use a Nikon D7100 that is not in the list but this is not my problem here).

I understand that Darktable uses regular expressions to check if the camera model from the exifs contains, for example, the expression "Nikon D7000" to auto-apply this base curve to the picture. But why are they not listed in the presets?

I don't want to change the auto-apply settings. I just want to see the other Nikon curves in the module in order to choose them manually (and then probably create a style including other modules).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since it *is* open source software, if you're so inclined you could hack on the [basecurve.c](https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/blob/master/src/iop/basecurve.c) file, which is pretty self-explanatory, and even includes a comment telling you where to paste your own custom generated base curve data...

If that's not your idea of a good time, the easiest, dirtiest hack would probably be to go into the "shortcuts" tab of the preferences, drill down to image operations>base curve>preset and temporarily bind some odd key combinations to the presets you want to try. Once you've applied one with the shortcut, you can save it as a normal preset in the usual way.

Honestly, though, you might be better off putting the effort into playing with the curve to get something you like; it's a useful skill to develop. ;)

Comment: I didn't fing on my disk the file  basecurve.c. I found a file  basecurve.cl that has a different structure... But your trick with the shortcut worked ! Weired that there is no more dirrect option to display these curves... Thanks !

Comment: I think the darktable developers have deprecated the shipping of camera-specific basecurves, and the ones that are still in the code are only because removing them would break some people's existing image processing stacks. It makes more sense for people to share these as *.dtstyle files, I guess... if you search for "basecurve" at [dtstyle.net](https://dtstyle.net/) you'll find a few.

Answer (score 1):

You could edit `darktable`'s SQLite DB file and copy a preset to your own. That's what I've done.